# What does clearing your cache three times do?

Tags: xbox-360

Why isn't once enough, and what is the purpose of clearing it three times for the following solution?

> Solutions<sup>[1](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/xbox-live/error-code-831188FE)</sup>
>
> Delete your gamertag, clear your cache, and recover your gamertag
>
> - Unplug any accessories attached to your console, such as a headset, the Xbox 360 Chatpad, or the Kinect sensor.
> - Delete your profile. For more information, see Download, move, or delete your Xbox 360 profile.
> - **Clear your system cache *three times*.** See How to clear your Xbox 360 system cache.
> - Recover your gamertag. For details, see Download, move, or delete your Xbox Live profile.
> - Update your security proofs. See Add and update security proofs for your Microsoft account.
> - Restart your console.
>
> If you keep getting the error, contact Xbox Support.

Comment: Sounds like something only the devs could answer, but a guess would be that it's an asynchronous operation that they (for whatever reason) don't wait for it to complete - making people perform it a couple of times may ensure the first completes in time.

Comment: It could also have something to do with dependencies: you never delete something, if something else depends on it, so you have to get rid of the children first, then get rid of the parents.

Answer (score -2):

Clearing the cache will completely eliminate all cache files. However some of them will come back. Clearing it 3 times will deter the files from coming back. I think the information is on a FAQ somewhere.

Comment: That sounds completely made-up